# Slow loading time when many tabs are open in vim

Tags: vim, delay

I am a tab hoarder. I have about 30 tabs open in gVim on average. As more tabs are open, it gets progressively slower to open a file via `tabedit`. It seems as though gVim cycles through every single tab that is open before opening a new one. Because, the scroll bar flickers while loading and each switch seems to corresponds to a tab that is open. (e.g. Two buffers in horizontal split has two scroll bars) Is this behavior a bug? Would it be possible to make it just jump to its tab and then open the file?
If I open file via `tabnew` then `edit` it does not suffer the delay.
Here is [the copy of my .vimrc](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1729951/.vimrc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `:tabopen` command.

The canonical command for opening a file in a new tab is:

```
:tabe[dit] filename
```

See `:help tabpage`.

Because of their design, Vim's tabs are poor proxies for files/buffers. I'd suggest you use a different method for managing multiple buffers, see `:help buffers`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `:tabe` instead of `:tabopen` I changed accordingly.

Comment: Could you share your `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: Yes. I added the link on the page. It is definitely my vimrc issue.

Comment: Try disabling `set guitablabel=%{GuiTabLabel()}` and `set guitabtooltip=%{GuiTabToolTip()}`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes. Taking out those functions entirely did the job for me. Could you please tell me how you found it out?

Comment: I started by looking around for `autocmd`s, then I remembered that `:tabedit` doesn't do that cycling you describe so I abandoned `autocmd`s and started to look around for commands/functions that worked on the tab labels… and bingo! Those functions seemed to do a lot but I didn't really have the time to tear them up, hence my suggestion to disable it. If the feature is important to you, you may investigate the inner workings of those functions and make them better.

Comment: I also found another problem. combining `tab drop` and `autocmd BufEnter`. Apparently if I open files with tab drop, it iterates through each buffer. This is not a big deal, until the `au` kicks in and make some delay on each iteration.

Comment: To be honest, your `~/.vimrc` is frightening: the number of autocommands, the obsession with tabs… You should really consider trimming it down. A lot.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a bug, a short way to reproduce it would be very helpful. But first ensure that nothing in your configuration or used plugins causes this. Try to reproduce in a clean Vim, started via:

```
$ vim -N -u NONE
```

Also, this may be caused by autocmds. When you see the problem, try `:set eventignore=all` and see whether it goes away.

If you can indeed reproduce this in plain Vim (of a recent build), please send your findings to the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).