# Showing tab number in gVim

Tags: vim

I thought I had a solution from [vim wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Show_tab_number_in_your_tab_line)(the very first solution), but it turned out to be a [bit buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184461/slow-loading-time-when-many-tabs-are-open-in-vim) for me since it slowed the file loading time. I could not find a plugin or other scripts. I was wondering if someone had a reliable script out there for showing tab number for each tab on gVim.

Comment: Did the below work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use this command:

```
:set guitablabel=%N
```

Comment: `set guitablabel=%N/\ %t\ %M` is more of what I was looking for, but I found what the problem is. I was using combination of `tab drop` as my default command for opening file (using `abbrev`). gVim iterates through each buffer when using this command. Therefore any `autocmd` with `BufEnter` slows down the loading time by a lot. Remove `BufEnter` or switching it with `BufReadPost` and then using `guitablabel` solved the problem for me. But `tab drop` needs to be improved so I am going to file a bug report.

Comment: That sounded tricky to determine what was causing the problem, hope they can fix the bug for you.